# Texture compression alpha

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, textures, alpha, multiplatform

Currently working with Unity, and I have some textures that I need to compress. I've tried several settings, but can't seem to find the one I need. Here are the specs :

- My textures are low-detail textures, so quality doesm't matter much.
- However, transparency is present and I need to keep that intact.
- I need this to work on pretty much all platforms (iOS, Android, PC, MAC) (No web or windows phone)
- I've tried RGBA Compressed PVRTC 4 bits (as suggested for iOS devices, I believe), but the transparency is messed up on mobile devices, for some reason.

Am I missing an obvious setting that I should be using ? Which one would be optimal ?

Comment: Can you include an image of what "messed up" means.  PVRTC is touchy; if you aren't already, try using a power of 2 square texture.

Comment: @Jerdak I am using a power of 2 texture (2048x2048). What I mean by messed up is simply that the transparency is lost.

Comment: Hmm, without knowing more the best I can suggest is to verify the problem is with Unity by using a texture from another paint program, something other than what you used.  There used to be an old bug with how Photoshop did alpha-fill that would crop up when saving compressed images.  You might also trying to writing a small device debug script to dump the alpha information to verify alpha data is being preserved.

Comment: Bypp, did you manually override texture format for iOS? Are you sure you have chosed RGBA PVRTC, not RGB PVRTC? Also you can try to compress your texture using PVRTexToolGUI and its variety of options. If the problem is in texture itself it help you to find a solution faster.

Comment: @gamedevelopmentgerm I didn't override the import settings, and yes I'm sure I took RGBA. The problem also occurs on Android devices, so I'm not sure what I should be doing.